# FZF-Vim with ripgrep: load results into quickfix list?

Tags: quickfix, plugin-fzf, ripgrep

I used to use the [vim-ripgrep](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-ripgrep) plugin to integrate with ripgrep (`:Rg`), which would load the results from `rg` into a **quickfix list**, so I could go back and forward over them with `[q` and `]q`.

Now I use the Fuzzy Finder (FZF) with [fzf-vim](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/fzf-vim) and am overall happy with how the `:Rg` command shows search results in FZF with a preview window, but once I select one search result, the others are gone (only workaround is to repeat the previous `:Rg` command).

Do you have any idea how I could get the quickfix list behaviour back?

Comment: [This answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68510609/1030985) looks promising!

Comment: Fwiw you don’t need a plugin for ripgrep support. It only takes two options to make `:grep` work: https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/plugin/rg.vim